# Matching all characters except spaces in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Right now I have a regex, and I want to change one part of the regex.

```
(.{3,}?) ~
```

^---This part of the code, where it says, (any characters that are 3 or more in length, and matches up to the nearest space), I want to change it to (any characters,  *except spaces* , that are 3 or more in length, and matches up to the nearest space). How would I say that in regex?

```
$text = "my name is to habert";
$regex = "~(?:my name is |my name\\\'s |i am |i\\\'m |it is |it\\\'s |call me )?(.{3,}?) ~i";
preg_match($regex, $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => my name [1] => my name )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => name [1] => name )
```

Comment: `/([^ ]{3,}) /` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Ghedipunk Why is the square brackets necessary? It doesn't work without them.

Comment: It's a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `[abc]` means to match one of a, b, or c.  With the caret (^) at the front, it means to not match anything contained in that character class.  In this case, it means to match any letter that isn't a space. You could extend it to any character that isn't any type of whitespace (tab, space, newline) by doing `[^\s]` or `[\S]`.

Comment: This regex is going to be very hard to match because of the spacing. The subject text has to be very exact.

Answer (score 1):

Gravedigger here... Since this question does not have an answer yet, I'll post mine.

---

`(\S{3,})` will work for your needs

---

**Regex Explanation:**

`(` Open capture group

`\S` Everything but whitespaces (same as `[^\s]`, you can use `[^ ]` too, but the latter works only for spaces.)

`{3,}` Must contain three or more characters

`)` Close capture group

[Test it here!](https://regex101.com/r/Zo3EfU/1)

Comment: `[^\s]` and `[^ ]` are not the same, `\s` is shorthand character class for `[ \t\r\n\f]`. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html